# I don't have a piercing

Tags: word-choice

Should I use the plural or the singular form of "piercing" no article or the indefinite article before it?

1."She's obsessed with (a) piercing(s)".

2."I don't like (a) piercing(s)."

3."I don't have (a) piercing(s)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you *don't* have a piercing, that means you don't have *even one*, so the singular is fine. You could equally say "I don't have piercings" and it would be understood the same way.

When it comes to the positive statement that someone *does* have piercings, the plural matters. "*She has a piercing*" would mean one, or at least one that is known or being discussed. "She has *piercings*" can only mean more than one.

Your example of "she's obsessed with piercings" could refer to the singular piercings of many people, or to piercings in general. Similarly "he's obsessed with cars" wouldn't mean that someone owns more than one car.

Comment: But "I don't like a piercing" doesn't sound natural, does it? It should be "piercings" but not zero article. And zero article is wrong in "she's obssed with piercing". Right?

Comment: "She's obsessed with piercing" would mean the practice of piercing rather than a particular example of it - and "obsessed with a piercing" would mean a particular one.

Comment: @AntoniaA No, "I don't like **a** piercing" doesn't sound right, because that would mean a particular piercing.

Comment: "obsessed with a piercing" would mean a particular one." Could you please explain what a particular one means?  But plural forms are correct , aren't they? "I am obsessed with piercings" and "I don't like piercings."

Comment: One piercing in particular. "She's obsessed with a piercing she saw in a photo; she's determined to get one like it." Yes, plural forms are correct for piercings in general.

Comment: But it makes sense as your whole sentence with added information not my stand alone sentence as just "She's obsessed with a piercing". Or is it also correct?